# Setting unique polygon fill color after loading GeoJSON into Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, style

New to Leaflet. I tried to set the fillColor to red. It is not working. I want each Polygon (there are less than 10 in this geoJSON) to have a unique color. Code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Leaflet sample</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
  integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
  crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
  integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"></script>

      ...
      <!-- HTML Page Elements are here -->
   </head>

   <body>
      <div id = "map" style = "width: 1990px; height: 1000px">This is a Canvas</div>
      <script>

var newMap = L.map('map').setView([38.9188702,-77.0708398], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: '&copy; <a href=”http://osm.org/copyright”>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(newMap);

var fillColor = "red"

$.getJSON("data/gpr.geojson",function(data){
// add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
            var datalayer = L.geoJson(data ,{
                     onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
                     featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAME_1); { color: feature.properties.fillColor };
                     }
                     }).addTo(newMap);
                     newMap.fitBounds(datalayer.getBounds());
                     });



      </script>
   </body>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#geojson) for `L.geoJSON` layer, you'll see that styling of GeoJSON features is done through `style` option, where you specify style function. This function receives feature as a parameter and must return style for that feature in the form of [path options](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#path-option). There is a nice example of this in the [Interactive Choropleth Map tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/).

In your case code could then look something like this:

```
$.getJSON("data/gpr.geojson", function(data){
  var datalayer = L.geoJson(data, {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, featureLayer) {
      featureLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAME_1);
    },
    style: function(feature) {
      return {
        fillColor: feature.properties.fillColor
      };
    }
  }).addTo(newMap);
  newMap.fitBounds(datalayer.getBounds());
});
```